# What sort of GUI controls are used in Windows Resource Monitor?

Tags: windows, winapi, perfmon

I am new to GUI programming in Windows.

The Windows Resource Monitor (`perfmon.exe /res`) has four bars (CPU/Disk/Network/Memory) that have gradient backgrounds, as well as charts on the right for displaying recent CPU/Disk/Network/Memory usage.

I am wondering what kind of controls were used in this application. Are they readily available in C++ or in C#?

[image]

Comment: Microsoft doesn't use controls much.  They paint instead.  More code but much cheaper on system resources and responsiveness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Spy++ window finder tool (Spy++ is included with DevStudio) to find the window class names (and window boundaries).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266028(v=vs.60).aspx

It shows that the overall window is a DirectUIHWND, the graphs are windows but the bars labelled CPU/Disk/Network, etc are not windows at all, the appear to be drawn directly in the resource monitors client area.

Answer (score 5):

They are custom controls that are not available for external use, sorry.

Comment: Well, at least you apologized.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

The implementation is not public for these controls, but I'm pretty sure they are incorporated using [Windowless Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8w12e5ak%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Those bars remind me of Outlook bars. One old implementation is described in [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/csoutlookbar.aspx), and that one also has no windows on its own. Everything is painted inside.

Edit: That Code Project article was C# port. For C++ original go to [Code Guru](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/controls/controls/article.php/c2155).